# Boto finding out when to use restore() to restore object from Glacier back to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have configured a life cycle policy on a bucket. Some objects are stored in S3, some are in Glacier. I am now trying to restore all objects from that bucket to local disk.

Using bucket.list() I get the list of objects. Objects that are in Glacier have storage class 'GLACIER' so I can call restore() for those. So far so good..

But.. the class is not an indication of whether the object needs to restored! According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-archival.html#restore-glacier-objects-concepts objects that are restored back from Glacier to S3 keep the storage class 'GLACIER'. So I can not use that to find out if a restore needs to be done or not. A restored object still has class GLACIER.

My question: how do I find out which objects are in Glacier only, and hence need to be restored() first. Currently in case of storage class 'GLACIER' I try get_contents_to_filename() first, if that fails I call restore().. but that does not feel right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you initiate a restore operation, S3 communicates back the status of that restore operation in the `x-amz-restore` response header of a `HEAD` request.  Boto will translate the value of that header to the `ongoing_restore` attribute of the `Key` object.  If the value of that attribute is `None` it means no restore has been requested or is in progress.  If the value is `True` it means the object is in the process of being restored but the operation has not yet completed.  If the value is `False` it means the restore operation has completed.  In that case, the `expiry_date` attribute of the `Key` object will be populated with the timestamp for when the restored object will expire and be removed from S3.

You could use something like this to check the status of a restore operation:

```
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
for key in bucket:
    if key.storage_class == 'GLACIER':
        full_key = bucket.get_key(key.name)
        if full_key.ongoing_restore is None:
            print('Key %s is not being restored' % key.name)
        elif full_key.ongoing_restore == True:
            print('Key %s restore is in progress' % key.name)
        else:
            print('Key %s has been restored and will expire %s' % (key.name, key.expiry_date))
```

The `get_key` call inside the loop is necessary to force a HEAD request on the object to get the metadata.  Otherwise you would only have the data returned by the LIST operation which does not include the object metadata.